# GCP Free trial - payment page not proceeding

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am facing issue when trying to make payment for GCP free trial ($300 credit 90 days plan). I am in India and using HDFC credit card.
I can go to Step 1 (personal details) and Step 2 (payment details), When I set up the payment method, it sends me the OTP for bank transaction and charges Rs 1.00 for verification. Then shows 'Processing.." page for 1-2 seconds but again redirects to Step 2. It does not show any error. Please see the attachments for the steps I follow.

I tried the below:
Clearing cache and history of the browser.
Using different browser (Safari instead of Google Chrome).
Using New Incognito window.
Using different user account.
Using different device.
Using different internet connection.
Unfortunately, none of the options worked.

I confirmed that the credit card I am trying to use for the payment is:
a mastercard, does not have two factor verification
has automatic recurring payments
has international transactions

Please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found that this is a know issue and being discussed on google's issue tracker.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186210363

As suggested in the threads, I installed Mozilla Firefox on Mac, and tried that same step. This time I got to Step 3 for account verification. This page says that my account is suspended as the account verification is pending. I followed the steps for verification. Now, waiting for their response.

I am closing this question in the hope that this should resolve the issue.

Fingers crossed !!